# VueJs2 computed not updating. Why?

Tags: javascript, sorting, vuejs2

I have an updated [grid example](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html) from official examples.
In my app need to move fill sortOrders array to

```
 created: function () {
        var vm = this;
        this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      vm.sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
  },
```

Tried to sort column but sorting happens only once.

Steps to reproduce:
click to "name" column header more then 1 time.
Expecting: column sorting each time when click to header of column
Got: column sorting only one time.

https://jsfiddle.net/xkkbfL3L/1916

Not understand why

```
Vue.set(this.sortOrders, key, order);
```

dosen't forcing `this.sortOrders` variable

It's works fine if use tmp variable like

```
   var order = this.sortOrders[key]*-1;
   var tmp = this.sortOrders ;
   Vue.set(tmp, key, order); 
   this.sortOrders = [];
   this.sortOrders = tmp;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xkkbfL3L/1919/

Comment: can you tell us what you were expecting and what you actually got?

Comment: Question has been updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from Vue Github https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6933

The problem is that app already create those keys before that moment, namely in created - and there don't use $set().

```
created: function () {
    var vm = this;
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
  vm.$set(vm.sortOrders, key, 1)
})
```

},

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/xkkbfL3L/1927/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Vue isn't firing the updates when you change 1 to -1 and to me that doesn't seem to be expected behavior. It may be worth [filing an issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues) on Vue's Github page and one of the vue devs may be able to explain more about this behavior. However as a quick workaround you can simply set `this.sortKey` to `null` before applying the updated key value:

```
sortBy: function (key) {
  this.sortKey = null;
  this.sortKey = key;
  var order = this.sortOrders[key]*-1;
  Vue.set(this.sortOrders, key, order);
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xkkbfL3L/1920/

Comment: Nice temporary solution. Thanks.